# itextsharp add 1 page template to all pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation, itext

I'm creating a PDF file dynamically in an ASP.Net application.
The data can vary from spanning 1 page to over 10 pages.
I'm using PdpfTables and Cells to align the data which is working perfectly. IT's creating pages as it needs new pages. The only problem is I can't get it to add my template to all pages, only the first page.

My Template is a 1 page PDF file. To add it to the first page I'm using the following code

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

As I said, this works for the first page fine but not any pages after that.
So I tried adding the following code just before I close all the streams, but it does nothing

```
for (var i = 2; i <= writer.CurrentPageNumber; i++)
{
    var y = (writer.PageSize.Height * (i - 1));
    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, y);
}
```

I've not really found anything on the net relating to my problem exactly, but those issues that are out there which are similar didn't help.

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: When you add a template at position (0, y) with y being greater than the height of the page, you're adding the template outside the visible area of the page. It beats me why you'd think that would work, and it really confuses people wanting to help you. You should accept mkl's answer. It's 100% correct.

Comment: Because the Y is the height of a page, there for my theory was that it would start on the next page. I am trying his answer now. It might work for you, but that doesn't mean it works in my situation!

Comment: Pages are separate entities. It's PDF, not HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want something to happen on each page, you should use page events and act in case of an `OnEndPage` call. The Webified iTextSharp Example [Stationery.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=Stationery) shows how to do that. It essentially post-initializes the `PdfWriter` to use an inner helper class as page event listener and retrieves the background:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
[...]
writer.PageEvent = new TemplateHelper(this);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(stationary);
page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
```

`page` is a member variable:

```
private PdfImportedPage page;
```

It is used by the `TemplateHelper` inner helper class:

```
class TemplateHelper : PdfPageEventHelper {
  private Stationery instance;
  public TemplateHelper() { }
  public TemplateHelper(Stationery instance) { 
    this.instance = instance;
  }
  /**
   * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(
   *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
   */
  public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    writer.DirectContentUnder.AddTemplate(instance.page, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Took a nights sleep to get my head around it but it's working now. I just need to fix the top margin for pages after the first. Shouldn't be difficult. Thank you very much