# Using Single Template for all PDF Pages in IText 7

Tags: java, itext7

I have the following *PDF template* which should be consistent for all the *pages* that gets added in the PDF I am creating ,

[image]

The issue is that, am getting this template only for *Page 1* and for rest of the pages only **blank template** is used , Here's the code am using right now,

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC),new PdfWriter(baosPDF));

PageSize ps = new PageSize(900, 780);

// Initialize document
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, ps);
document.setMargins(80f, 20f, 50f, 20f);

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    document.add(new Paragraph("Some Content"));
    document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
}
document.close();
```

I have referred this [itextsharp add 1 page template to all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917433/itextsharp-add-1-page-template-to-all-pages) example already , but I need something specific to Itext 7 since it varies a lot from 5.x.x versions

how do I get my PDF to have the single template as shown in image to be common for all the pages ?

Comment: Please read the tutorial. More specificly: the chapter about [handling events](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-writer-properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you need to create an `IEventHandler` as described in [chapter 7 of the tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-writer-properties)

This is an example from the PDF to HTML tutorial ([chapter 4](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml)).

```
class Background implements IEventHandler {
    PdfXObject stationery;

    public Background(PdfDocument pdf, String src) throws IOException {
        PdfDocument template = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
        PdfPage page = template.getPage(1);
        stationery = page.copyAsFormXObject(pdf);
        template.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
            page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdf);
        pdfCanvas.addXObject(stationery, 0, 0);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 32, 36, 64);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rect);
        canvas.add(
            new Paragraph(String.valueOf(pdf.getNumberOfPages()))
                .setFontSize(48).setFontColor(Color.WHITE));
        canvas.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, we read the template in the constructor, and we draw it to the Canvas in the `handleEvent()` method. In this example, we also add a page number in white, you can remove all those lines.

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
    PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
    PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
        page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdf);
    pdfCanvas.addXObject(stationery, 0, 0);
}
```

Obviously, you also need to declare the handler:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
IEventHandler handler = new Background(pdf, stationery);
pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net(C#) version of the code:

```
//Call the handler before multiple page generation
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
IEventHandler handler = new Background(pdfDocument, @"YourTemplateFilePath");
pdfDocument.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, handler);

public class Background : IEventHandler
{
   PdfXObject stationery;

   public Background(PdfDocument pdf, String src)
    {
        PdfDocument template = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
        PdfPage page = template.GetPage(1);
        stationery = page.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
        template.Close();
    }

   public void HandleEvent(Event @event)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
        page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdf);
        pdfCanvas.AddXObjectAt(stationery, 0, 0);
    }
}
```